error: [Dagger/DuplicateBindings] in multi module project when using @Qualifier annotation
@Qualifier annotated implementations of an interface fails to compile when used in a clean architecture style multi-module project.
Say we have the following module structure: :domain, :presentation (includes :domain), :data (includes :domain).
In :domain we define
interface RepositoryInterface

// and annotation
@Qualifier 
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class SomeRepository1Annotation

Then in :data we define implementation
class SomeRepository1 : RepositoryInterface

// and provide dependency
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object DataModule {

    @SomeRepository1Annotation
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideSomeRepository1(): RepositoryInterface = SomeRepository1()

In :presentation we try to inject several implementations of the same interface
class Main @Inject constructor(
    @SomeRepository1Annotation val repo1: RepositoryInterface,
    @SomeRepository2Annotation val repo2: RepositoryInterface,

It fails to compile with error: [Dagger/DuplicateBindings] org.daggercleanarchitecture.domain.RepositoryInterface is bound multiple times:
But interestingly enough this same setup compiles just fine when using @Named annotation.
Error log
\daggercleanarchitecture\AndroidApplication_HiltComponents.java:127: error: [Dagger/DuplicateBindings] org.daggercleanarchitecture.domain.RepositoryInterface is bound multiple times:
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements FragmentGetContextFix.FragmentGetContextFixEntryPoint,
                         ^
          @org.daggercleanarchitecture.domain.SomeRepository1Annotation @Singleton @Provides org.daggercleanarchitecture.domain.RepositoryInterface org.daggercleanarchitecture.data.DataModule.provideSomeRepository1()
          @org.daggercleanarchitecture.domain.SomeRepository2Annotation @Singleton @Provides org.daggercleanarchitecture.domain.RepositoryInterface org.daggercleanarchitecture.data.DataModule.provideSomeRepository2()
      org.daggercleanarchitecture.domain.RepositoryInterface is injected at

